# Spinner is not populating with the data recieved from webservice

Tags: android, json, web-services, spinner

I am creating an android application for my client and in this app the user have to fill a form. I am using JSON web service for this purpose and I know how to send and receive data. Problem is that while I am fetching necessary data to fill the form and populating the spinner (I have multiple spinners in my form) the data doesn't populate to the spinner however I am successfully getting the data from web service. Please review my code and kindly help me because i don't have much time remaining. Thanks in advance.

```
public class AgentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spnr_commodity;
    public Spinner spnr_ImpExp;
    public Spinner spnr_unit;
    public Spinner spnr_terminal;
   public Spinner spnr_eta;
    public Spinner spnr_lastport;

    private String TAG = "Agent";
    private TextView txtName_L;
    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtloa;
    private TextView txtbeam;
    private TextView txtgrt;
    private TextView txtnrt;
    private TextView txtpcno;


    private ImageButton btnSearch;
    private SearchView shipSearch;
    private String strShipName = "Select Ship Name";
    private String str_qty;
    private AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.8F);
    /*private AnimationSet edtQty = new AnimationSet();*/
    EditText a_date;
    EditText d_date;

   EditText a_time;
    EditText qty;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog1;
    DatePickerDialog  datePickerDialog2;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Toolbar mToolbar;

   public String [] arr_impexp= {"Type","Import","Export"};
    public String[] arr_lastport={"Select ","KPT","Singapore","China","Dubai","Indonesia","Korea"};

    public String[] arr_shipname ;
    public String[] arr_terminal;
    public String [] arr_commodity  ;

    ArrayAdapter<String> unitAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> terminalAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> commodityAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> ImpExpAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> lastportAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences preference = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setTitle(preference.getString("nameKey", null));


        setContentView(R.layout.agent_activity);





        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });


        txtName_L = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.l_shipName);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.n_ship);
        txtloa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loa);
        txtbeam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beam);
        txtgrt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grt);
        txtnrt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nrt);
        txtpcno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pc);

        btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
        qty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.c_qty);
        a_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_date);
        d_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.d_date);
        a_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_time);
      spnr_ImpExp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_ImpExp);
        spnr_ImpExp.setPrompt("Type");
        spnr_unit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_unit);

        spnr_terminal = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_terminal);

        spnr_eta = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_eta);

        spnr_lastport = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_lastport);


//download data from php
        new DownloadInitialInformation().execute("http://192.168.1.131/pqamssql/agent.php");



        txtName_L.setText(strShipName);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Select Unit ");
        list.add("TUE");
        list.add("M.Ton");
        list.add("C.Met");
        list.add("Units");
        unitAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item, list);
        unitAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnr_unit.setAdapter(unitAdapter);

        ImpExpAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, arr_impexp);
        ImpExpAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnr_ImpExp.setAdapter(ImpExpAdapter);

        txtName_L.setText(strShipName);

        //  str_qty = qty.getText().toString();
        //  Toast.makeText(this,"QTY: "+str_qty,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        txtName.setText("SHIP NAME |  " + Constants.getShipName());


        if (!Constants.getShipName().equals(" ")) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Ship Name : " + Constants.getShipName());

            new ShipDetail().execute("http://192.168.1.131/pqamssql/initial.php?shipname=" + Constants.getShipName());

        }

        spnr_unit.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        if (position != 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                                    "Position: " + position + " OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            String str_craftType = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            //craft.setText(str_craftType);
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // v.startAnimation(buttonClick);
                Intent i = new Intent(AgentActivity.this, AgentListView.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        // initiate the date picker and a button

        // perform click event on edit text
        a_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog1 = new DatePickerDialog(AgentActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                a_date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog1.show();
            }
        });



        d_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog2 = new DatePickerDialog(AgentActivity.this,R.style.agentTheme,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                d_date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                datePickerDialog2.show();
            }
        });

        a_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                // Get the current hour and minute
                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int mint = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AgentActivity.this,R.style.AppTheme_Light_Dialog, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        a_time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    }
                }, hour, mint,true);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });


    }



    class ShipDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.i(TAG, "URL : " + params[0]);
            String result1;
            String result2;
            String result3;
            String result4;
            String result5;

            String[] resultArray = new String[5];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                Log.i(TAG, "Data Read");
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line);

                }


                String json = buffer.toString();
                Log.i(TAG, "LINE ## : " + json);
                if (json.equals("No Data Found")) {

                    resultArray[0] = "No Data Found";


                } else {
                    JSONObject shipdetailObject = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONObject parentKey = shipdetailObject.getJSONObject("detail");


                    result1 = parentKey.getString("loa");
                    result2 = parentKey.getString("beam");
                    result3 = parentKey.getString("grt");
                    result4 = parentKey.getString("nrt");
                    result5 = parentKey.getString("pcno");
                    resultArray[0] = result1;
                    resultArray[1] = result2;
                    resultArray[2] = result3;
                    resultArray[3] = result4;
                    resultArray[4] = result5;

                    return resultArray;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return resultArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] s) {


            super.onPostExecute(s);

            if (s[0].equals("No Data Found")) {
                Toast.makeText(AgentActivity.this, "" + s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String str_loa = s[0];
                String str_beam = s[1];
                String str_nrt = s[2];
                String str_grt = s[3];
                String str_pcno = s[4];


                Log.i(TAG, "Extracted From JSON LOA: " + str_loa);
                Log.i(TAG, "Extracted From JSON BEAM: " + str_beam);
                Log.i(TAG, "Extracted From JSON GRT: " + str_grt);
                Log.i(TAG, "Extracted From JSON NRT: " + str_nrt);
                Log.i(TAG, "Extracted From JSON PCNO: " + str_pcno);

                txtloa.setText("L.O.A    |" + str_loa);
                txtbeam.setText("G.R.T     |" + str_beam);
                txtgrt.setText("N.R.T    |" + str_grt);
                txtnrt.setText("BEAM    |" + str_nrt);
                txtpcno.setText("P.C No.  |" + str_pcno);
            }


        }
    }

    //downloading initial detail
    class DownloadInitialInformation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
          progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AgentActivity.this,
                    R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
          //  progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.i(TAG, "URL : " + params[0]);

//Boolean flag= new Boolean(false);
          String flag = "";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                Log.i(TAG, "Data Read");
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line);

                }


                String json = buffer.toString();
                Log.i(TAG, "LINE ## : " + json);
                if (json.equals("No Data Found")) {
flag="N";
                }
                else{
                    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray parentShipArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Ship");
                    JSONArray parentTerminalArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Terminals");
                    JSONArray parentCommodityArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Commodity");

                    int v_len,t_len,c_len;
                    v_len = parentShipArray.length();
                    t_len = parentTerminalArray.length();
                    c_len = parentCommodityArray.length();
                    arr_shipname = new String[v_len];
                    arr_terminal = new  String[t_len];
                arr_commodity = new String[c_len];


                    Log.i(TAG, "Ship Length : " + v_len);
                    Log.i(TAG, "T Length : " + t_len);
                    Log.i(TAG, "C Length : " + c_len);
                    //getting ships
                    for (int i = 0; i < v_len; i++) {
                        JSONObject  ship_json  = parentShipArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       arr_shipname[i] = ship_json.getString("v");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Ship name : " + arr_shipname[i]);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Vessel name : "+arr_shipname[2]);

                    }


                    //getting terminals
                    for (int i = 0; i < t_len; i++) {
                        JSONObject  terminal_json = parentTerminalArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        arr_terminal[i] = terminal_json.getString("t");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Terminal : " + arr_terminal[i]);
                    }

                    //getting commodity

                    for (int i = 0; i < c_len; i++) {
                        JSONObject    commdty_json = parentCommodityArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //  arr_commodity.add(commdty_json.getString("c"));
                        arr_commodity[i] = commdty_json.getString("c");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Commodity : " + arr_commodity[i]);
                    }

                    flag = "Y";


                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return flag;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String downloadStat) {


            super.onPostExecute(downloadStat);
            Log.i(TAG, "download stat : " + downloadStat);
            if (downloadStat.equals("Y")) {
//set all textViews and spinner

               // Log.i(TAG, "Commodity : " + arr_commodity[1]);


                spnr_commodity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_commodity);
                commodityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AgentActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arr_commodity);
                commodityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //Log.i(TAG, "Commodity : " + arr_commodity);
                spnr_commodity.setAdapter(commodityAdapter);

                terminalAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AgentActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr_terminal);
                terminalAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spnr_terminal.setAdapter(terminalAdapter);
                //Log.i(TAG, "Terminal : " + arr_terminal.toString());

                lastportAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AgentActivity.this,android. R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr_lastport);
                lastportAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
                spnr_lastport.setAdapter(lastportAdapter);
                //Log.i(TAG, "Last Port : " + arr_lastport.toString());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AgentActivity.this, "No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
} // End of AgentActivity

*LogCat to Check populated array*

11-14 09:44:18.267  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ (QICT)-1.1
11-14 09:44:18.267  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ (QICT)-1.2
11-14 09:44:18.267  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ (QICT)-2.1
11-14 09:44:18.267  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ (QICT)-2.2
11-14 09:44:18.268  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ EVTL-13
11-14 09:44:18.268  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ FAP GT
11-14 09:44:18.268  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ FOTCO OIL TERMINAL
11-14 09:44:18.268  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ IOCB
11-14 09:44:18.268  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ LCT
11-14 09:44:18.269  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ MW-1
11-14 09:44:18.269  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ MW-2
11-14 09:44:18.269  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ MW-3
11-14 09:44:18.269  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ MW-4
11-14 09:44:18.269  19660-19660/com.portqasim.personal.testinglayout I/TERMINAL﹕ SSGC/LPG
```

Comment: declare your  arr_commodity,arr_terminal,arr_lastport array variables global and try

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: no luck brother :( 

you can check my code again if i made any mistake. here is the link 
http://pastebin.com/9Q7p1d90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved successfully by just changing the spinner mode from dialog to dropdown

*Previously*

android:spinnerMode="dialog"

*Now*

android:spinnerMode="dropdown"

the previous xml is here

http://pastebin.com/2G9zt8ht

the correct xml is here

http://pastebin.com/yQEbapkg

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your spinner in the xml file. But I had similar issue and was fixed when I added entries in my spinner in the xml. I had all my adapter and spinner items all right but wouldn't get displayed in the spinner without adding the entries in the xml file.

Comment: Add android:entries="@array/whatever_your_content" in your spinner

Comment: i m not using string resource array and i googled to make string resource programmatically so i got to know that i can not make it at run time. so now how can i apply your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the adapter to spinner after getting all values in list, debug your code and make sure your list has data in it before setting adapter to spinners.

Comment: I didn't mean that, just check the values in those arrays.

Comment: Just make sure that before setting adapter to spinner, array is not null

Comment: yes, array is not null i have placed log to check the array and it is showing extracted values